# Is there any problem to solve the lag in dbeaver (mac os)?

Tags: dbeaver

Dbeaver has been lagging, takes around 10/15 mins just to rename the table. Even tried uninstalling along with the associated system files and re installed it. I have been using
dbeaver version 21.2.1.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot for the command being used which takes time? What is the version of jdbc driver being used in this connection? What is the connection type being used, externalbrowser or snowflake?